# Set() methods for enums between classes

Tags: java, enums

Let's say I have the following code in a class:

```
enum Currency
{
  PENNY(1), NICKEL(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
  private int value;
  private Bonus(int value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
};
public class Coin
{
  Currency c;
  public Coin(Currency c)
  {
    this.c = c;
  }
  public void setCurrency(Currency c)
  {
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

If I have a separate class that creates Coin objects with a certain Currency enum, how could I write a method in that separate class to set the enum from, say, PENNY to DIME?

Comment: Can you provide example of using this method? I don't understand what should it do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call the method setCurrency in coin class from the separate class you created and pass the currency enum you want to set it.

example:

Lets say you create a Coin object with a currency enum as PENNY:

```
Coin coin = new Coin (Currency.Penny);
```

Now you can create a separate method in the separate class you want to call this and set the new currency enum as:

```
coin.setCurrency(currency.DIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, what you have done makes sense. Since you have defined the `enum` in the `same java file` as the `public class`, the `enum's scope` will be `default` and it can be `accessed` only in the `same package`.

So I would suggest `moving` it out to `another file` and make it `public`.